# Replace line with only part of the line

Tags: linux, vim, regex, command-line

I have a large table from Wikipedia (from the wiki source), and I want to extract a single column, I have it open in vim, and what I want to extract looks something like this

```
|col||[[what I want]]||another column||another one||et cetera|
```

Every line has content I want, so I tried:

```
:%s/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/\1
```

But I get the error

```
E486: Pattern not found: \[\[(.+?)\]\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would cut the content out first, then open it in vi:

```
cat wikifile.txt | cut -d \| -f 4 > foo
vi foo
```

Two steps, but two steps I can always remember without much thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
:%s/.*\[\[\(.*\)\]\].*/\1/
```

which will return

```
what i want
```

I.e. you need to

- escape the group brackets "(" and ")" and also
- match the part before and after the interesting column because you want to replace it.

Comment: Probably safer to use '[^]]*' in place of '.*' in case there are two fields with the double-square brackets around them.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :

```
1,$ s/^\(.*\[\[\)\(.*\)\(\]\].*\)$/\2/
```

It check from the begin of the line to [[ -> put it in atom 1, the sentence -> atom 2, the end of line -> atom 3.

Then just display atom 2.